# How do I make the height of a slider match that of an image relative to the width of the window?

Tags: javascript, html, css, slider, responsive-design

So I'm trying to make my website super responsive, but I want to include this image slider I found. I was able to make the width of the slider responsive so that when the window shrinks, so does the image. Unfortunately, I can't get the height of the slider to adjust to the height of the image within it. Is there any way I can do this with the javascript or css? Here's the slider javascript within the html:

```
<div id="slider_container_2" class="canvas">
    <div id="SliderName_2" class="SliderName_2">
        <img src="demo_2/img/1.jpg" usemap="#img1map" />
        <map name="img1map">
            <area href="#img1map-area1" shape="rect" coords="100,100,200,200" />
            <area href="#img1map-area2" shape="rect" coords="300,100,400,200" />
        </map>
        <!-- Description <div class="SliderName_2Description">College Graduations 2013</div> -->
        <img src="demo_2/img/2.jpg" />
        <img src="demo_2/img/3.jpg" />
        <img src="demo_2/img/4.jpg" />
        <img src="demo_2/img/5.jpg"/>
        <img src="demo_2/img/6.jpg" />
        <img src="demo_2/img/7.JPG" />
        <img src="demo_2/img/8.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="c"></div>
    <div id="SliderNameNavigation_2"></div>
    <div class="c"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        effectsDemo2 = 'rain,stairs,fade';
        var demoSlider_2 = Sliderman.slider({container: 'SliderName_2', width: '100%', height: 325, effects: effectsDemo2,
            display: {
                autoplay: 5000,
                loading: {background: '#000000', opacity: 0.5, image: 'demo_2/img/loading.gif'},
                buttons: {hide: true, opacity: 1, prev: {className: 'SliderNamePrev_2', label: ''}, next: {className: 'SliderNameNext_2', label: ''}},
                description: {hide: false, background: '#000000', opacity: 0.4, height: 50, position: 'bottom'},
                navigation: {container: 'SliderNameNavigation_2', label: '<img src="demo_2/img/clear.gif" />'}
            }
        });
    </script>
    <div class="c"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe if you use jsFiddle we could see the CSS along with the HTML and jQuery. I am just learning so excuse the question but I don't understand that the width of the container is set to 100% but the height is 325. Do you not have to say 325px or something?